# Solving coupled second order differential equations with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have two coupled differential equations of the form:

$\frac{\partial^2 T_1}{\partial x^2} - \frac{1}{R_{1,2}} \left ( T_1-T_2 \right )=0$

$\frac{\partial^2 T_2}{\partial x^2}-\left ( \frac{1}{x} \right )\frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x} - \left ( \frac{1}{x} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{R_{2,3}} \right )\left ( T_2-T_1 \right )=0$

I am trying to analytically solve for the general form of $T_1(x)$ and $T_2(x)$. I can apply boundary conditions on my own after that to find the form of my constants. Normally, I'd opt for a matrix solution $x'=A*x$, but the $1/x$ terms seem to make that approach unusable (to my knowledge).

Any advice on how to analytically solve this?

Comment: The condition for the matrix approach is that $A(x)$ must commute with itself at different  $x$. Have you tested that yet?

Comment: I have not. I wasn't able to form an A matrix without having 1/x terms inside my A matrix.

Comment: Read my comment again - it is okay to have a nonautonomous matrix (i.e. a matrix $A(x)$ dependent on a variable instead of $A$). What you need to check is if $A(x_1)$ commutes with $A(x_2)$. Edit the attempt to check this property in your post. Additionally just as a sanity check, your matrix should be $4\times4$ since this is a two equation system of *second* order equations

Comment: Also multiply the second equation by $x$ before putting it in the matrix - it will make your calculations easier even if it is not in standard form.